# AttributeError: can't set attribute after import chaco.api

Tags: python, chaco

I installed [chaco](http://docs.enthought.com/chaco/user_manual/chaco_tutorial.html) library on windows server 2012 after too much headache but I faced a big problem after installation :

> pip install chaco
> Requirement already satisfied: chaco in c:\programdata\anaconda ...
> Requirement already satisfied: enable>=5.2.0 in c:\programdata\ ...
> Requirement already satisfied: numpy in c:\programdata\anaconda ...
> Requirement already satisfied: traits>=6.2.0 in c:\programdata\ ...
> Requirement already satisfied: pyface>=7.2.0 in c:\programdata\ ...
> Requirement already satisfied: traitsui in c:\programdata\anaco ...
> Requirement already satisfied: fonttools in c:\programdata\anac ...
> Requirement already satisfied: pillow in c:\programdata\anacond ...
> Requirement already satisfied: importlib-metadata in c:\program ...
> Requirement already satisfied: importlib-resources>=1.1.0 in c: ...
> Requirement already satisfied: zipp>=3.1.0 in c:\programdata\an ...

but after I import Chaco I get an error from "enable":

```
from chaco.api import (
    DataView,
    ArrayDataSource,
    ScatterPlot,
    LinePlot,
    LinearMapper,
    BarPlot,
    PlotAxis,
    FilledLinePlot,
    add_default_grids,
    Legend,
    PlotGraphicsContext,
    DataRange1D,
    VPlotContainer,
    PlotLabel,
    DataLabel, )
```

and this is my runtime error :

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "c:\tsetmc\botsar.py", line
> 41, in 
> from chaco.api import (   File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\chaco\api.py", line 343,
> in 
> from chaco.overlays.api import (   File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\chaco\overlays\api.py",
> line 63, in 
> from chaco.overlays.layers.api import (   File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\chaco\overlays\layers\api.py",
> line 11, in 
> from .status_layer import ErrorLayer, StatusLayer, WarningLayer   File
> "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\chaco\overlays\layers\status_layer.py",
> line 17, in 
> from enable.savage.svg.document import SVGDocument   File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\enable\savage\svg\document.py",
> line 27, in 
> from . import css   File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\enable\savage\svg\css_*init*_.py",
> line 10, in 
> from .transform import transformList   File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\enable\savage\svg\css\transform.py",
> line 18, in 
> from enable.savage.svg.pathdata import number, maybeComma   File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\enable\savage\svg\pathdata.py",
> line 118, in 
> lineTo = Group(Command("L") + Arguments(coordinatePairSequence))   File
> "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\enable\savage\svg\pathdata.py",
> line 29, in Command
> return CaselessPreservingLiteral(char)   File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\enable\savage\svg\pathdata.py",
> line 44, in **init**
> self.name = "'%s'" % matchString AttributeError: can't set attribute

Does anyone have any idea to solve this issue? I could have installed Chaco last year but this error never happen before and I don't know what to do

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem might be because of updates in 'enable' API.

I removed the `self.name` in pathdata.py and I got the error that customName cannot be found! Therefore, I change `self.Name` to `self.customName` and it solved